# Can I have a NgModule providing other NgModules?

Tags: angular

I have an Angular 7 app that I am trying to extract some functionalities to a separate library, and share it with other apps.

I want to know if it is possible to have a single `NgModule` that includes every other module:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  imports: [
    AuthModule, (..many other modules)
  ],
  exports: [SomeComponent]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
  ],
  declarations: [MyAuthComponent],
  providers: [MyAuthService, MyOtherAuthService],
  exports: [MyAuthComponent]
})
export class AuthModule{
```

In the end, I wish to import the `SharedModule`  into my app and use the `AuthModule` and `AuthServices`.

For example, in my app routes config, I want to have a route pointing to `MyAuthComponent`, and another secure route that uses `MyAuthService` to validate if an user can navigate.

I am failing to see how to configure the modules:

```
import { MyAuthComponent } from '@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.component';
```

Gives me an error that it can't be resolved.

Is this scenario at all possible or should I build this another way?

Comment: Do you re-export your `MyAuthComponent` in the `public-api.ts` in your shared library?

Comment: No, only the AuthModule itself:
@NgModule({
  imports: [AuthModule],
  exports: [AuthModule]
})
export class SharedModule {
}

Comment: Can u post the content of your `public-api.ts` file of your shared lib? I guess there is a missing export of the `MyAuthComponent`.

Comment: There is a bunch of other stuff there that the other developers put. I was not aware of that file. Should I add my module or also the services and components?

Comment: Everything that should be accessible from the user of the library. So probably yes: the module, components and services but you can decide. Sometimes it is wanted to hide a service/component from the usage outside of its own module. Then you wouldn't export it.

Comment: Now I got:
export * from './lib/shared.module';
export * from './lib/auth/auth.module';
export * from './lib/auth/auth.component';
export * from './lib/auth/auth.service';

Still, I can't make this work.

import { SharedModule, AuthModule, AuthComponent, AuthService} from '@mylib/shared';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...
    SharedModule,
    AuthModule,
    AuthComponent,
    AuthService
  ],
  providers: [... ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lengthy conversation it the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203691/discussion-between-thomas-cayne-and-saita) we found two things that were misconfigured:

- In order to be able to access the `AuthComponent` class in typescript from a different application we had to export it in the `public-api.ts` file of the library.
- The import of the `AuthComponent` has to point to `@mylib/shared` instead of `@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.component`.
- I would like to add that sometimes we get really hard to find bugs when a component is accidentally configured in a `imports: [ ABCComponent ]` section or a vice versa, a module within the `declarations: []`.

Answer (score 0):

You export all modules you imported in ShareModule.ts:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [SomeComponent],
  imports: [
    AuthModule, (..many other modules)
  ],
  exports: [
    SomeComponent, (...all components you want to share),
    AuthModule, (...many other modules)]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
     ngModule: SharedModule,
     providers: [(...all shared services if you have them)],
   };
}}
```

In your AppModule.ts:

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot(),...
]
```

But in other modules.ts, etc

```
imports: [
    SharedModule,...
]
```

No `.root()`

Comment: So as I build new modules, I need to add their individual Services to the "ModuleWithProviders", or can I just add the module itself there?
Example:
ngModule: SharedModule,
     providers: [AuthModule, OtherModule]

And then in the AuthModule I export the Service:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
  ],
  declarations: [AuthComponent],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuardService],
  exports: [AuthComponent, AuthService, AuthGuardService]
})
export class AuthModule {

?

Comment: Add the modules in `imports: [...]` and `exports: [...]`. You don't have to put your services in `ModuleWithProviders`. Declare them like: `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) export class MyAwesomeAndCoolService { ...}` And they can be accessed through the application by importing them wherever you will use them.

Comment: In all my years I'm only added one provider in `ModuleWithProviders`. `imports...exports` will suffice. Then import `SharedModule` in other modules throughout the app

Comment: I got: 
@NgModule({
  imports: [AuthModule],
  exports: [AuthModule]
})
export class SharedModule

And:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    SharedModule
  ]...
})
export class AppModule

When trying to use the service:

const routes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: 'mypath',
    component: MyComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthService] 
  },
  { 
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

Comment: Also, in the route module, I have: 

import { AuthService } from '@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.service';
import { AuthComponent } from '@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.component';

And I get:
ERROR in ./app-routing.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.service'...
ERROR in ./app-routing.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.component'...

Comment: You don't import services in your route modules. You import them in components constructor: `import { AuthService } from '@mylib/shared/lib/auth/auth.service'; constructor(private AuthService : authService ) {}`. Route module is to direct your application to the various modules with components or components.

Comment: Think of a module which contains a routing module, components, and services; you export from that module the components and providers if you want them shared with other modules. Then you import that beautiful module into another module or AppModule and all can be shared.

Comment: If you want to route to that module you have to add it as route in your route module: `path: 'admin', loadChildren: () =>import('./admin/admin.module').then(lazy => lazy.AdminModule)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203691/discussion-between-thomas-cayne-and-saita).